# ng-click is not sending value to the angular controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a form and trying to send the value of the input to the angular controller but on click, the value in the controller is showing undefined.
html code

```
<div ng-if="questioncode == 2" class="user-form">
          <div class="row">
          <form>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <label class="control-label" >Phone number</label>
            </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="your phone number" ng-model="phone">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <input  type="submit" class=" col-sm-12 btn btn-primary" ng-click="submituserPhone();"  >
                 <flash-message   duration="3000" show-close="true" on-dismiss="myCallback(flash);" ></flash-message>
              </div>
              </form>
          </div>
       </div>
```

angular controller

```
  $scope.submituserPhone = function() {
console.log($scope.phone);
  $http.post('insertphone',$scope.phone),then(function() {
    if(response.data.status === false) {
      Flash.create('danger',response.data.message);
    }else{
      $scope.questioncode = 3;
    }
  })


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is the `ng-if` which is creating a new scope, hence the scope variable `phone` is not getting updated in the controller. Here are two methods to tackle this problem.

**Using $parent:**

You can use `$parent` to update the variable of the parent scope instead of the current one, then your variable will be visible inside the controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.questioncode = 2;
  $scope.submituserPhone = function() {
    console.log($scope.phone);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-if="questioncode == 2" class="user-form">
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label">Phone number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="your phone number" ng-model="$parent.phone">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="submit" class=" col-sm-12 btn btn-primary" ng-click="submituserPhone();">
          <flash-message duration="3000" show-close="true" on-dismiss="myCallback(flash);"></flash-message>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Pass the variable as a parameter:**

You can simply just pass the variable of the created scope into the controller function and update it there, as shown below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.questioncode = 2;
  $scope.submituserPhone = function(phone) {
    $scope.phone = phone;
    console.log($scope.phone);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-if="questioncode == 2" class="user-form">
    <div class="row">
      <form>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label">Phone number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="your phone number" ng-model="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="submit" class=" col-sm-12 btn btn-primary" ng-click="submituserPhone(phone);">
          <flash-message duration="3000" show-close="true" on-dismiss="myCallback(flash);"></flash-message>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```